# MATLAB: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch - Inserting Image

Tags: matlab, dimension

I have been struggling with this error for a few days now. The code is trying to insert an image into a larger one, however I cannot get past this error.

I have read many others answers to this problem and understand that most likely the two matrices are not of the same size, however I cant seem to find where the problem is.

```
        function SetRegion(obj, fileName, x, y)  %insert an image
        yIn = y;    %y coordinate of insertion
        xIn = x;    %x coordinate of insertion

        newIm = imread(fileName);   %read in new image
        sz_n = size(newIm);         %get size of new image for later use

        %check for correct coordinates
        if ( (yIn > obj.sz(1)) || (xIn > obj.sz(2)) )    %coordinates are not within image
            disp('These coordinates are not within the image.');
            %exit function
        end     

        %set x coordinates for modification
        if ( (xIn + sz_n(2)) > obj.sz(2) )
            Px = obj.sz(2);
            xInEnd = obj.sz(2) - xIn;
        else
            Px = xIn + sz_n(2);
            xInEnd = sz_n(2);
        end

        %set y coordinates for modification
        if ( (yIn - sz_n(1)) < 1 )  %image needs to be cropped vertically
            Py = 1;
            yInEnd = sz_n(1) - yIn;
        else
            Py = yIn - sz_n(1);
            yInEnd = 1;
        end

        %insert image
        obj.im(Py:yIn, xIn:Px, :) = newIm(yInEnd:sz_n(1), 1:xInEnd, :); 


    end %function setregion
```

The exact error i get is as follows:

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

> Error in Picture/SetRegion (line 85)
>               obj.im(Py:yIn, xIn:Px, :) = newIm(yInEnd:sz_n(1), 1:xInEnd, :);
>
> Error in PictureTest (line 17) SetRegion(a, 'Photo3.jpg', 20, 20);

If anyone can spot something I am doing wrong or provide any tips I would really appreciate it.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your help. After you confirmed that this was the error I worked through as suggested and was able to find the areas where I need a +/- 1 to correct the sizes. Thank you for the assistance, it is much appreciated.

Comment: what are the values of `Py`,`yIn`,`Px` and `xIn` when the error happens?

Comment: and the values of `size( obj.im(Py:yIn, xIn:Px, :) )` and `size( newIm(yInEnd:sz_n(1), 1:xInEnd, :) )`

Comment: Py = 24, yIn = 200, Px = 300, xIn = 200

Comment: size( obj.im(Py:yIn, xIn:Px, :)) = 177 101 3

Comment: size(newIm(yInEnd:sz_n(1), 1:xInEnd, :)) = 176 100 3

Comment: Do you see the potential issue with trying to fit something of size 176 100 3 into something with size 177 101 3?

Comment: @nkjt yes I can see why this is an issue. I am having trouble finding the source of it however in relation to inserting the new image into the original. I think the fact that MATLAB uses matrices starting at 1 is messing with me along with the coordinate origin being top left not bottom left.

Comment: Often the issue is that you have to think of the fact that a section of matrix which is, say, `n:(n+sz)` or `(n-sz):n` actually has length `sz+1`. Working it out on paper/at the command line and then stepping through your code in debug mode will help you pin down where the error is coming from.